# SQL server, rows to columns using row over partition

Tags: sql-server

I have a structure like the below...

Person 
  - personid

```
  Skills
      - skillid
      - personid
      - skill
```

So one person will have many skills. My question is how do I write a join to show skills as columns.

In a past job a colleague achieved this using row over partition but I'm struggling to figure how. I know a pivot is an option but my preference would be row over partition.

Any ideas?

Comment: You will probably need both for that example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use dynamic sql if the maximum number of skills is unknown. You will need to use [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to number each list partitioned by `PersonId` for use with [**`pivot()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx).

test setup:

```
create table t (skillid int, personid int, skill varchar(32));
insert into t values (1,1,'sql-server'),(3,1,'sql'),(9,2,'sql-server');

declare @cols nvarchar(max);
declare @sql  nvarchar(max);

  select @cols = stuff((
    select distinct 
      ',' + quotename('Skill_'
          +convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over (
              partition by PersonId 
              order by     Skill 
          ))
          )
      from t 
      for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
    ,1,1,'');

select @sql = '
 select PersonId, ' + @cols + '
  from  (
    select 
        PersonId
      , Skill
      , rn=''Skill_''+convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over (
          partition by PersonId 
          order by     Skill 
          ))
      from t
      ) as a
 pivot (max([Skill]) for [rn] in (' + @cols + ') ) p';
 select @sql as CodeGenerated;
 exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/OFHO71002

code generated:

```
select PersonId, [Skill_1],[Skill_2]
  from  (
    select 
        PersonId
      , Skill
      , rn='Skill_'+convert(nvarchar(10),row_number() over (
          partition by PersonId 
          order by     Skill 
          ))
      from t
      ) as a
    pivot (max([Skill]) for [rn] in ([Skill_1],[Skill_2]) ) p
```

returns:

```
+----------+------------+------------+
| PersonId |  Skill_1   |  Skill_2   |
+----------+------------+------------+
|        1 | sql        | sql-server |
|        2 | sql-server | NULL       |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Yes true skill count is unknown.

Comment: I will test this asap and post a comment will probably be tomorrow morning. Thank you for replying

Comment: I didnt have chance to test this yesterday as an issue cropped up however I did use the row over partition technique you posted to fix another issue so thanks for that!